# Button click is not working in C# + Appium but working fine in Java

Tags: java, c#, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a scenario to be test on Mobile website having below steps:
1. Open [Gmail](https://www.gmail.com)
2. Enter your Email
3. Click Next button
4. Enter your password
5. Click Sign In

Below is the code which is working fine with Appium + Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar")).sendKeys("https://www.gmail.com");  
driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);  
driver.findElement(By.name("Enter your email")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");  
driver.hideKeyboard();  
driver.findElement(By.name("Next")).click();  
driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("test@123");  
driver.findElement(By.name("Sign in")).click();
```

Below is the code using Appium + C#, which is not working:

```
driver.FindElementById("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar").SendKeys("https://www.gmail.com");  
driver.KeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.Enter);  
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("test@gmail.com");  
driver.HideKeyboard();  
driver.FindElement(By.Name("Next")).Click();  
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("android.widget.EditText")).SendKeys("test@123");             
driver.FindElement(By.Name("Sign in")).Click();
```

I am facing 2 issues in code using C#.

1. Could not able to click on Sign in button.
2. To enter email (test@gmail.com) in text field **By.name** is not working in C# but working fine in Java.

Can any one please help in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I'm struggling with the same issue.